# porque mi servicio WCF no retorna valor de lista correctamente?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

Tengo un servicio en VS2015 que utiliza clases de EntityFramework para obtención de datos, he programado unos metodos localmente y funcionan, pero cuando expongo un metodo que retorne un tipo List resulta que solo funciona cuando realizo un filtro por Find().Este mi código

```
using (var dc = new ModeloDBTestEntities())
{
   if (id != null && id != 0)
   {
      var oplan = dc.Plans.Find(id);
      return new List<Plans>() { new Plans { Id = oplan.Id, Nombre = oplan.Nombre, Tipo = oplan.Tipo } };
   }
   else
   {
      List<Plans> lstplans=new List<Plans>();//AQUI USO EL MISMO CONTEXTO
      lstplans=dc.Plans.ToList();//<- PERO ESTA LISTA ES INCAPAZ DE RETORNARLA

      return lstplans;
   }

}
```

Supongo que por editar manualmente mi clase(tratar de ponerla en singular y luego regrasarla), quedó así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Anexo detalle en video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zddQEfouMZM&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el principal problema es que está retornando otro tipo de datos:

`System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Plans_XXXX` en lugar de `System.Generic.Collection.List<Plans>`

Sin embargo, no deberías de estar retornando entidades sino DTOs. Por eso mismo, te recomendaría crear una clase PlansDTO:

```
public class PlansDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Y realizar el mapeo:

```
var plans  = dc.Plans.ToList().Select(planEntity=> new PlansDTO
   {
       Id = planEntity.Id, 
       Nombre = planEntity.Nombre, 
       Tipo = planEntity.Tipo
   });
```

No olvides cambiar el tipo de retorno de `List<Plans>` a `List<PlansDTO>` y mapear cuando utilizas `Find`:

```
return new List<PlansDTO>() { new PlansDTO { Id = oplan.Id, Nombre = oplan.Nombre, Tipo = oplan.Tipo } };
```

Comment: ok, poniendo eso, en la última línea me manda "el operador ?? no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo IQueritable<Plans>".Paso seguido agrego .ToList() al LINQ, sin embargo al ejecutar reclama: The entity or complex type 'AseguradoraDBTestModel.Plans' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Comment: Agregué una imagen mi clase de contexto , para comprender porqué devuelve ese Entity.DynamicProxies

Comment: @AlfonsoCastañeda revisa le edición, por favor.

Comment: al final, tube que hacer un foreach para acomplar a la clase estándar:  foreach (var itm in dc.Plans)
                    {
                        var _plan=new Plans { Id = itm.Id, Nombre = itm.Nombre, Tipo = itm.Tipo };
                        lstplans.Add(_plan);
                    }
                    return lstplans;

Comment: Pero estás exponiendo entidades de EF, un buen diseño expone DTOs no entidades.